# Apache PDFBox - can't decrypt PDF

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have a problem with decrypting a PDF document with Apache PdfBox (v1.8.2) lib. Encryption works, but decryption with the same password throws an exception. (Java 1.6)

```
package com.test;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.AccessPermission;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.StandardDecryptionMaterial;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.StandardProtectionPolicy;

public class PdfEncDecTest {

    static String pdfPath = "G:\\files\\filed5b3.pdf";
    public final static String PDF_OWNER_PASSWORD = "cd1j";
    public final static String PDF_USER_PASSWORD = "";  

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdfPath);
        AccessPermission ap = new AccessPermission();
        ap.setCanPrint(true);
        ap.setCanExtractContent(false);
        ap.setCanExtractForAccessibility(false);
        StandardProtectionPolicy spp = new StandardProtectionPolicy(PDF_OWNER_PASSWORD, PDF_USER_PASSWORD, ap);
        document.protect(spp);
        document.save(pdfPath+".pdf");
        document.close();

        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(pdfPath+".pdf");
        if(doc.isEncrypted()) {
            StandardDecryptionMaterial sdm = new StandardDecryptionMaterial(PDF_OWNER_PASSWORD);
            doc.openProtection(sdm); // org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.CryptographyException: Error: The supplied password does not match either the owner or user password in the document.
            doc.decrypt(PDF_OWNER_PASSWORD); // the same like above
        }
        doc.close();
    }

}
```

I don't know what is wrong. With version 1.8.7 I get the same exception. I've posted the full code above.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.CryptographyException: Error: The supplied password does not match either the owner or user password in the document.
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.StandardSecurityHandler.prepareForDecryption(StandardSecurityHandler.java:265)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.StandardSecurityHandler.decryptDocument(StandardSecurityHandler.java:156)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.openProtection(PDDocument.java:1595)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.decrypt(PDDocument.java:942)
    at com.test.PdfEncDecTest.main(PdfEncDecTest.java:29)
```

I've put sample project to github: https://github.com/marioosh-net/pdfbox

Comment: Please try again with the current version (1.8.7). If it still doesn't work, please include the exception in your question.

Comment: i got the same exception with 1.8.7 version...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the user password.

```
    if (doc.isEncrypted())
    {
        StandardDecryptionMaterial sdm = new StandardDecryptionMaterial(PDF_USER_PASSWORD);
        doc.openProtection(sdm);
        // don't call decrypt() here
    }
```

this works even if the user password is not null. The user password is for what the ordinary human thinks encryption is, the owner password is an encryption for the security rights.

edit: sorry, my answer is wrong, although it was helpful. You can open a PDF with the user password (you'll possibly get restricted rights) or with the owner password (you'll get full rights). What may have happened is that there is a bug with matching the owner password with 40bit keys (which is the 
default). This bug is currently being investigated, see [PDFBOX-2456](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2456) and search for "MD5".

Comment: i need set ONLY security rights on pdf, user password has to be empty

Comment: even then, your code is still wrong, your file is user-encrypted with the empty password, so you need to pass that one and not the owner password at that time.

Comment: Hmmm... You are right! I've checked this. Thank You very very much!

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and it work's fine for me.

i am using

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I've put sample project to github: `https://github.com/marioosh-net/pdfbox` You can check. It doesn't work for me :(