# encryption exception with PDFBox while the file is readable

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) for extracting text from PDF file in java. It works fine in most of the cases but I have problem with some PDF files as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
```

The files have following properties

[image]

Is there any way by which I can open this type of files to extract their contents?

I guess I am getting this error because I try to extract texts page by page. And the page extraction here is not allowed! But, as the picture suggests Content Copying is allowed. Also, I can open the file and see the content! Then, there should be a way for opening and getting the content of these files. Right?

This [Link](http://www.assembly.pe.ca/sittings/2015spring/journal/2015-06-19-journal.pdf) is an example of PDF file with which I have problem.

The Exception occured at the following line if `objNr = 9`

```
securityHandler.decryptStream(stream, objNr, objGenNr);
```

Then, if I set the program to proceed to this line if `objNr != 9` it works fine! Does someone know why it happens? I have another PDF file which work when `objNr != 10`. any idea?

The code that I have (tested with the latest version of the [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) just to try and see if my problem is because of the version I use) is as follows

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PDFManager pdfManager = new PDFManager();
        pdfManager.setFilePath("PathToThePDFFile");
        System.out.println(pdfManager.ToText());
    }
}


import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


public class PDFManager {
    private PDFParser parser;
    private PDFTextStripper pdfStripper;
    private PDDocument pdDoc ;
    private COSDocument cosDoc ;

    private String Text ;
    private String filePath;
    private File file;

    public PDFManager() {

    }
    public String ToText() throws IOException
    {
        this.pdfStripper = null;
        this.pdDoc = null;
        this.cosDoc = null;

        file = new File(filePath);
        parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));

        parser.parse();
        cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
        pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
        pdDoc.getNumberOfPages();
        pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
        pdfStripper.setEndPage(10);
        Text = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
        return Text;
    }

    public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
         this.filePath = filePath;
    }
}
```

Comment: That the file is readable with Adobe Viewer is because it is encrypted but with an empty user password, and a non empty owner password, which is why you don't have all the rights. Now about the exception: this is a known problem in newer JDK versions. Some - but not all such problems - have been fixed in the current version 1.8.9. Sadly, you did not mention what version you are using.

Comment: And it might be useful to upload the PDF somewhere.

Comment: I even tried the latest version of PDFBox (1.8.9) available on the apache website but it told me that the file is encrypted.  I have added a link to the PDF file which has the mentioned properties to the question. Is there any way by which I can pass this problem to extract the content of the document?

Comment: I tried and was able to extract text with the command line tool ExtractText. Please edit your question to show what code you used. (Did you call openProtection() after load())?

Comment: I have added the source code that I have tried with the latest version of the library! I have not 'override' anything but I got "file is encrypted" message! Have you noticed about the numbers that I mentioned in my question? (9 and 10) do you have any idea why it happens?

Comment: I can't tell about the 9 and 10 thing. What I can tell you is that your code is wrong, as it doesn't call openProtection so I don't know what happens then with an encrypted file. Here's an example how to call openProtection and how to open documents correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295553/apach-pdfbox-cant-decrypt-pdf